# Ruby sshkit IPv6 string addressing issues

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, sshkit

I'm sure this is an issue on my end that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding. I am using `sshkit` to connect to and upload some files to a server with IPv6 addressing.

I can SSH into a server with an address like so:

`2001:aaa:bbb:cc:dddd:eeee:ffff:gggg`

There is no issues until I try to leverage `sshkit` to do the same. The below example illustrates how the same IPv6 string is represented in an array (which has many addresses) within the script I am running:

`on ["[2001:aaa:bbb:cc:dddd:eeee:ffff:gggg]"], in: :parallel do |host|
  #some stuff
end`

What I end up seeing is:

`Exception on host 2001:aaa:bbb:cc:dddd:eeee:ffff caught: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Note the trailing byte seems to be truncated off? Is there a different way I should be formatting that IPv6 address string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with SSHKit at the moment which I am planning to submit a PR for. Essentially the trailing bytes are swallowed as the port number unless specifically denoted.

```
### Without port number, it parses incorrectly
SSHKit::Host.new '[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]'
 # => #<SSHKit::Host:0x007fc12318d7d8 @keys=[], @local=false, @user=nil, @hostname="2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370", @port=7348>
```

The work around is to specify the port

```
### With port number it works
SSHKit::Host.new '[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:22'
 # => #<SSHKit::Host:0x007fc1231e46c8 @keys=[], @local=false, @user=nil, @hostname="2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348", @port=22>
```